# Factorizar en numeros primos python

Tags: python

tardes o noches, tengo una duda, tengo que hacer una función que descomponga un numero y me devuelva todos sus divisores primos (con todo y sus repetidos), pero no logro que me de eso... los repetidos, por ejemplo el numero 1274 = 2 * 637, 637 = 7 * 91, 91 = 7 * 13  y deberia quedar algo asi:
1274 = 2 · 637 = 2 · 7 · 91 = **2 · 7 · 7 · 13**

Necesito que me devuelva lo que esta en negritas pero solo me devuelve un 7 de los 2

Aqui estan mis funciones

```
def es_primo(x):
  for d in range(2, math.floor(math.sqrt(x))+1):
    if(x%d == 0):
      return d
  return 0

def factorizar(x):
  divisores=[]
  divisores_primos=[]
  if es_primo(x) == 0:
    return x
  else:
    for d in range(2, math.floor(math.sqrt(x))+1):
      if(x%d == 0):
        divisores.append(d)
      
    for i in range(len(divisores)):
      if es_primo(divisores[i]) == 0:
        divisores_primos.append(divisores[i])
    
    if divisores_primos == []:
      print("No hay divisores primos en x")
      return 
    else:
      return divisores_primos, divisores
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta parte

```
  else:
    for d in range(2, math.floor(math.sqrt(x))+1):
      if(x%d == 0):
        divisores.append(d)
```

obtienes la lista de divisores, pero sólo pasas una vez por cada divisor. Además, dejas factores sin considerar, pues no recorres el rango completo. El límite que utiliza sólo detecta el factor primo menor, pero el primo complementario. Por ejemplo, para 15, el `for` itera hasta el valor 3, dejando el valor 5 sin considerar.

Tienes que cambiar el rango para obtener todos los divisores y cambiar el `if` por un `while`, el divisor se agregara a la lista tantas veces como corresponda:

```
    for d in range(2, x):
        while (x % d == 0):
            divisores.append(d)
            x //= d
```

#### Demo

```
print(factorizar(1274))
print(factorizar(4482))
```

produce:

```
([2, 7, 7, 13], [2, 7, 7, 13])
([2, 3, 3, 3, 83], [2, 3, 3, 3, 83])

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo estaba en ese while :D